# Align vertically center Bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how can I align a third column vertically?
[I want third column vertically centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmh7D.png)

```html
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    
<div class="col-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
<div class="col-4">
      One of three columns
    </div><div class="col-4">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
```

thanks

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

Try this  if you want as in your attach otherwise i do not understand what you are looking for :

```
  <div class="col-12 row">
        <div class="col-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
    <div class="col-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
    </div>
```